# Smoothly speed up an running rotation animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I use this code to rotate any view:

```
func rotateAnimation(theView: UIView, duration: CFTimeInterval = 20.0, repeatCount: Float = 200, toValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(.pi * 2.0)) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = toValue
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    theView.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

I would like to know how to speed up that currently running animation. If for example an UIView is rotating with the code above, how can I make that speed go twice as fast with a nice transation?

So: *calls rotateAnimation*: rotating at normal speed -> *calls ?function?* -> UIView will smoothly go spinning faster to desired speed -> UIView will keep spinning at desired speed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: does changing the duration help?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Nope, it changes the speed but after a few seconds the animation is back to its original speed.

Comment: On the same note as changing the duration, have you tried a while loop with the condition line specifying the final position of the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try Below Code

```
       let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            self.viewToMove.layer.timeOffset = self.viewToMove.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
            self.viewToMove.layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            self.viewToMove.layer.speed += 0.5

        }
        timer.fire()
```

It will Increase Animation speed very smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the second animation

You can set smaller duration to increase speed

```
func rotateAnimation(theView: UIView, duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.4, repeatCount: Float = 200, toValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(.pi * 2.0)) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = toValue
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
```

And set shouldRasterize = true for better performance

```
    theView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    theView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Use the same key for both animations

```
    theView.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: "animation")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set repeatcount to 1 and re-add the animation after each animation stopped. I'm not sure if this cause performance issue in your scenario since I tested it with a very basic square view.

By adding a `CAMediaTimingFunction` parameter, you're able to control whether to use `kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear` -- for those normal animation loops, or to use a custom one, such as `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn` -- for the key animation frame to show a smooth transition.

```
// your function to start the acceleration
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    accel = true
    speed = 2.0
    timeOffset = self.rect.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    timeOffset = timeOffset - lastStart
    // memorize the timeoffset, new speed (2x) and a boolean flag
    self.rect.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}

// delegate - memorize the CFTimeInterval
func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {
    lastStart = self.rect.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
}

// delegate - start a new loop of animation each time it's stopped
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if accel {
        accel = false
        let opt = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.5, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7)
        rotateAnimation(theView: rect, speed: speed, fromValue: CGFloat(.pi * 2.0 * Float(timeOffset) / 10.0), toValue: CGFloat(.pi * 2.0 * Float(timeOffset) / 10.0 + .pi * 2.0), option: opt)
    } else {
        rotateAnimation(theView: rect, speed: speed, fromValue: CGFloat(.pi * 2.0 * Float(timeOffset) / 10.0), toValue: CGFloat(.pi * 2.0 * Float(timeOffset) / 10.0 + .pi * 2.0))
        // note that timeOffset is initialize to be 0.
    }
}
```

You want a custom CAMediaTimingFunction here, start by a slope of 0.5 and gradually increase to 1.0, I didn't optimize the bezier curve here, you can do your own desired curve.

Finally a little tweak to your animation function:

```
func rotateAnimation(theView: UIView, speed: Float, duration: CFTimeInterval = 10.0, fromValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(0.0), toValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(.pi * 2.0), option: CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = fromValue
    rotateAnimation.toValue = toValue
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.speed = speed
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = 1
    rotateAnimation.delegate = self
    rotateAnimation.timingFunction = option
    theView.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```