# CABasicAnimation which loops, but goes to different values each time?

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation

Imagine you have a

```
anime.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

and it is animating something back and fore between values ..

```
2  9  2  9  2  9  2  9  2  9  2  9 etc
```

but what you want is

```
2  9  3  7  3  8  1  9  3  8  1  7 etc
```

So - change the `.fromValue` and `.toValue` each time to slightly random values.

In fact, if you are changing the from and to values each time...

in fact **do you have to just drop the animation and start a new one**??

(So, you'd use `setCompletionBlock` and do that.)

Or, can you just set it to loop forever, but, change the targets each time?? Is there a way?

Comment: Is the sequence of random numbers infinite or otherwise really long? Otherwise you could just create a keyframe animation with all of the values and loop that.

Comment: In that case I think you're best of adding a new animation once the previous one finishes.

Comment: The animation object is copied when it's added to the layer, so any modifications to it after that will not be propagated to the render tree.

Comment: ah!  that's really the awesome answer @DavidRönnqvist, surely you should put that in as an answer for googlers??  thanks .........

Comment: If you want to . change speed,  You can change the speed of animation  like  this 
 My answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45975774/4601900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation object is copied once it is added to the layer, so any modifications to it after that will not be propagated to the render tree. See the [documentation for `add(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410848-add).

In other words, you can't modify an animation once it has been added to the layer. Instead you would remove it and add a new animation.

---

There are some "tricks" that could make it look like a series of random values — for example keyframe animations or multiple additive animations with different durations — but none of them achieve an actual animation of infinite random values.

To accomplish that you're best off adding a new animation once the previous one finishes over and over indefinitely.

Comment: this would have to be one of the best answers on the whole site

Comment: @Fattie If that is so, is there anything missing from it that makes it not answer your question? If not, is there a reason why it's not accepted?

Comment: hey @DavidRönnqvist , simple, I always pay a bounty on questions :)  (You can look through the history.) you have to wait a couple days to do it

Comment: That explains it :)

Comment: For anyone googling here, it does seem to be that the only way to do "what I ask in this question", in the iOS milieu, is to use a "restartable animation".  Indeed, here is our code base for doing a "restartable" core animation, maybe it will same someone some typing .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787919/294884